# Avoiding jumping frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays

Sometimes I want an element on a frame to change in steps.
I do this by

```
\only<2>{  
...  
}  
\only<3>{  
...  
}
```

etc.

But this causes the frame to jump due to different sizes of the included content.
How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Wrap your code fragment inside the `overlayarea` environment.

Answer (score 65):

This issue is addressed in the `beamer` manual in section 9.5 *Dynamically Changing Text or Images*, p.85 for v.3.10.

You need to use either the `overlayarea` environment which is "more flexible but less user friendly" or the `overprint` environment.

```
\begin{overlayarea}{⟨area width⟩}{⟨area height⟩}
  ⟨environment contents⟩
\end{overlayarea}

\begin{overprint}[⟨area width⟩]
  ⟨environment contents⟩
\end{overprint}
```

You then need to use `\onslide<⟨num⟩>` instead of `\only<⟨num⟩>{...}`.
The numbers must be disjoint.

Example:

```
\begin{overprint}
  % on every slide (not sure if it is officially supported)
  \onslide<1>
  % on first slide
  \onslide<2>
  % on slide two
  \onslide<3>
  % on slide three
  % etc.
\end{overprint}
```

Comment: Using `\only` within either an `overprint` or `overlayarea` environment seems to work fine.  Also, `\onslide` doesn't behave the same as `\only`, so sometimes `\only` may be preferred.

Comment: No, `\only` does not work as intended. Also, very important is to *not* use braces around `onlide`'s "arguments" (even if they are necessary for the same construct in `overlayarea`). Using braces makes the elements *not* overlap at all as they should.

Comment: I am using ``overlayarea`` with ``only``. Is it possible to make ``overlayarea`` choose its own area height, which should be equal to the height of the longest ``only<>`` entry?

Answer (score 23):

The jumping occurs because beamer normally vertically centres the content on the frame.

One way to achieve a constant starting point for content of all heights(*) is to tell beamer to top align the frame. This can either be done on a frame-by-frame basis with

```
\begin{frame}[t]
```

or globally for the whole presentation:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    \only<1>{abc}

    \only<2>{abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc }
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

(*) at least for all heights which don't overflow the available text height.

Comment: Perfect, the simplest way out for many situations I'd imagine.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with figures, it can be sufficient to use `\tikz[overlay]` inside `\only`:

```
\only<.>{
  \tikz[overlay,xshift=0em,yshift=0ex]{\draw node {
      % content goes here
   };}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a command phantom to build a same size of the elements.

```
\only<2>{
...
}
\only<2>{
\phantom{xxxx}
}
\only<3>{
xxxx
}
```

Comment: This can result in movement of common items.  Using overprint as suggested in other answers avoids this problem.

Comment: For many cases, this will probably suffice. This is exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that encapsulating the content of each step in textblocks often solves the problem of jumping frames. This is an example for a frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\only<1->
{ 
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(10mm,0.2\textheight)
% first content
\end{textblock*}
}
\only<2->
{
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(10mm,0.5\textheight)
% second content
\end{textblock*}
}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a full example, instead some fragments. Another reason of jumping frames could be omitted `%` characters ;-)