# Change alertblock content in beamer in a new frame

Tags: beamer, block

I'm looking for a method to change the content of an `alertbox` in beamer when the user moves to the next frame.

A solution is of course to generate two frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Foo}
Bar1
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\begin{alertblock}{Foo}
This is a very long text that should be displayed on two or more lines, as a result, the alertblock will enlarge and thus cause the audience to focus more on the box than the content that is of course the important part of the presentation.
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this approach is however that if `Bar2` has not the same vertical span width as `Bar1`, the box is repositioned resulting in an ugly visual effect.

As a result in the first slide, an `alertblock` is displayed containing `Bar1` but already has the size to show `This is a very...`, in the second slide `This is a very...` is displayed starting at the top-left of the `alertblock`.

Comment: You should use one `alertblock` and then include overlay specifications for the contents. As in `\begin{alertblock}{Foo}
\onslide<1>{Bar1} \par \onslide<2>{Bar2} \end{alertblock}`, say. Perhaps a more concrete example highlighting your problem would help.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `Bar2` is placed below `Bar1`

Comment: Use the `overlayarea` environment to specify the area that should be kept the same. As such, I think the following is a duplicate: [Avoiding jumping frames in `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148/5764)