# Beamer document jumping of alignment

Tags: beamer

I would like to make a frame, with a piece of text, then the appearance of a picture and after that another line of text appearing. I am using the code below, but if I click for the picture to appear, the first line of text jumps to a higher position in the slide. How to resolve this?

```
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Text
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics<2->[]{file.pdf}
\end{figure}
\item<3-> Text
\small
\begin{eqnarray} \nonumber
*formula*
\end{eqnarray}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I think you should have a look to [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148/13304).