# Text with overlay is vertically displaced in beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, overlays

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Displacement of text}

\only<1-2>{This text will be displaced.}

\only<2>{Did you see it?}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `\only<1-2>` text is vertically displaced from its original position. Why does this happen?

I also tried this:

```
\only<1-2>{

\only<1-2>{This text will be displaced}.

\only<2>{Did you see it?}

}
```

but the same phenomenon happens.

I would like for the text not to "move": if it appears at some position, to stay there during the whole frame.

I searched the internet and tex.stackexchange, but I couldn't solve this.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Have you seen this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer ?

Comment: You need to use `overprint` or `overlayarea` to ensure everything takes a constant space. Otherwise, it is displaced because there is less stuff on one slide than the other and `beamer` adjusts whatever is on the slide according to how much of it there is so that content is roughly vertically centred.

Comment: Yeah, the `\overlayarea` worked! The documention of it is at section 9.5 of the Beamer User Guide. Thank you guys very much.

Comment: @Adam didn't you see that the vertical position of "This text will be displaced" slightly changes before and after the "Did you see it?"

Comment: @Larara to tell you the truth no I didn't notice it.

Comment: Yeah, it is a subtle change. Anyway thanks for your attention and time spent on helping me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `overprint` if the slide specifications are disjoint so I think you need `overlayarea` in this case. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Displacement of text}

    \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.3\textheight}

      \onslide<1-2>{This text will be displaced.}

      \onslide<2>{Did you see it?}

    \end{overlayarea}

  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```