# How to fix tikzpicture size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

In a beamer presentation I am using tikz to draw graphs. To highlight part of the graph I am using overlay and the fit library as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
    \node<2>[draw=red, line width=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b)]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This solution works fine, excepted that there is a little shift of the whole frame when the user click the mouse to reveal the higliht rectangle drawn with fit. I guess that this comes from the fact that addiding this fit node changes the bounds of the tikzpicture. How can I remove this annoying shift behaviour ?

Comment: One way is to fake it by adding `\node<1>[draw=white, line width=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b)]{};` into your tikzpicture above the `\node<2>...` line... I'm sure there is a better way, so I won't put this as an answer :-)

Comment: That would have been my first guess, too. If you add `opacity=0` it doesn't hide anything in the background.

Comment: I think [avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer) is a duplicate. Would you agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also a TikZ library for this problem (`overlay-beamer-styles`).

The solution with this library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \node[draw=red,line width=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b), draw on=<2->]{};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution, which avoids printing a white frame or using transparency:
The node is placed in the first slide, but not drawn. Because of the missing draw operators, the bounding box is updated manually using the
node.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
    \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of a] (b) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
    \node<1>(tmp)[line width=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b)]{}
      (tmp.south west) (tmp.north east); % update bounding box
    \node<2>[draw=red, line width=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b)]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what `(tmp.south west) (tmp.north east)` do.  I understand you create a `tmp` node which fits nodes `a` and `b` but I don't know how calling coordinates `tmp.south west` and `tmp.north east` updates anything. Could you explain it?

Comment: @Ignasi `(tmp.south west) (tmp.north east)` are simple "moveto" operations, which updates the bounding box of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: what is the meaning o `<1>` in `\node<1>`?

Comment: @Viesturs Point brackets are used for overlay specifications, a feature of class `beamer`, see chapter "9 Overlay specifications" in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: If before slide 1 I insert 2 other slides will I have to update `<1>` to `<3>`?

Comment: @Viesturs Please, read the documentation; it also contains a tutorial, section "3.10 Using Overlay Specifications".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using Beamer's `overlayarea`. The only real disadvantage is that you have to specify the height of the area.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{TEST}
  \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.3\textheight}
  \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1-2>{
      \node[draw=black, rectangle]             (a) {A};
      \node[draw=black, rectangle, right=of a] (b) {B};
      \draw (a) -- (b);}
    \only<2>{
      \node<2>[draw=red, line width=1.5pt, fit=(a) (b)]{};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{overlayarea}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: stop wobble with <code>overlayarea</code>]