# Avoiding jumps when using beamer overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have the following piece of code in a beamer slide to put the curly brackets under the equation on the second slide:

```
\begin{equation*}
    a = \alt<1>{b+c+d}{\underbrace{b+c+d}_{\text{some text}}}.
\end{equation*}
```

This causes jumps in the slides.  I was wondering how I should avoid this?

I tried to wrap the `equation` inside an `overprint` environment (as suggested in [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer)) but it didn't help.

Thanks for your helps in advance!

Comment: Add a phantom of the underbrace to the first slide

Comment: Which part of `underbrace` should be put inside `phantom`?

Comment: This code does not reproduce the problem even when the obvious document structure is added because the underbrace is never shown. Since only one slide is produced, no jump is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a new environment `overlayauto` which works like `overlayarea` but computes the height, width and depth from the data.

Note: this is like putting an `\mbox` in a math environment in that you need to use $...$ inside.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{environ}

% used to replace \only
\def\testonly<#1>#2{\setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
  \ifdim\ht0>\maxheight\relax\maxheight=\ht0\fi
  \ifdim\dp0>\maxdepth\relax\maxdepth=\dp0\fi
  \ifdim\wd0>\maxwidth\relax\maxwidth=\wd0\fi
}
\NewEnviron{overlayauto}[1][\normalfont\raggedright]% #1 = minipage optons
{% get dimentsions from data
  \dimendef\maxheight=0
  \dimendef\maxwidth=1
  \dimendef\maxdepth=2
  \maxheight=0pt
  \maxdepth=0pt
  \maxwidth=0pt
  \let\temp=\only
  \let\only=\testonly
  \BODY
  \let\only=\temp
  \raisebox{0pt}[\maxheight][\maxdepth]%
    {\begin{minipage}[t]{\maxwidth}
      #1\BODY
    \end{minipage}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
above
\begin{equation*}
a=\begin{overlayauto}
\only<1>{$b+c+d$}%
\only<2>{$\underbrace{b+c+d}_{\text{some text}}$}
\only<3>{$\overbrace{b+c+d}^{\text{some text}}$}
\end{overlayauto}
\end{equation*}
below
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```