# \phantom \begin{figure} does not work

Tags: spacing, floats, white-space, phantom

Why doesn't this work?

```
\phantom{
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics{fig.pdf}
      \end{figure}
}
```

It outputs

```
Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

I'm trying to do something like this

```
\begin{frame}
  \only<1>{%
    \begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
      Cool table & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\\hline
      $a$ & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
      $b$ & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}\\
  }
  \only<2>{%
    \begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
      Cool table & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\\hline
      $a$ & 1 & \color{red}1 & 0 \\
      $b$ & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}\\
  }
  \only<3>{%
    \begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
      Cool table & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ \\\hline
      $a$ & 1 & 1 & \color{red}0 \\
      $b$ & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}\\
  }
  \only<2>{%
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics{../shared/arrows_0.pdf}
    \end{figure}
  }
  \only<3>{%
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \includegraphics{../shared/arrows_1.pdf}
    \end{figure}
  }
\end{frame}
```

And I don't want the table or the picture to jump.

Comment: Well figure is rather complex environment. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: And don't use the H specifier unless you really knows what it does and when to use it.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: use `\visible` or `\uncover` instead of `\only`. Check the beamer docu about the differences.

Comment: The problem is that if I have a figure in an \uncover environment, this means that on every other slide, I have a whitespace in the size of the figure, which is not what I want. I only want this whitespace on the first slide.

Comment: So the real issue is how to avoid jumps using beamer.  There are several similar questions here.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269903/avoiding-jumps-when-using-beamer-overlays?r=SearchResults&s=1|63.6325 for example.