# Is this a Beamer with Animation on Tables bug?

Tags: tables, beamer, pdftex, columns, animations

On the second slide of the animation, the following code results in the first table being offset down the page. Is this a bug?

Note that this is different from [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148/avoiding-jumping-frames-in-beamer) in that the accepted solution is different from the proposed solutions there.

(Sorry if the example isn't exactly minimal, but it does show the problem.)

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{multicol}
%used to place text free on the slide
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{pifont}

\definecolor{dblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{dgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.8}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Example\footnote{\tiny Taken from \url{http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/viswanathan/Median_Test.html}}}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\onslide<1->{\begin{table}
\tiny
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    A &  B \\ \hline \hline
    79   &   85\\ \hline 
    86   &   80\\ \hline 
    40   &   50\\ \hline 
    50   &   55\\ \hline
    75   &   65\\ \hline 
    38   &   50\\ \hline 
    70   &   63\\ \hline 
    73   &   75\\ \hline 
    50   &   55\\ \hline 
    40   &   45\\ \hline 
    20   &   30\\ \hline 
    80   &   85\\ \hline 
    55   &   65\\ \hline 
    61   &   80\\ \hline 
    50   &   55\\ \hline 
    80   &   75\\ \hline 
    60   &   65\\ \hline 
    30   &   50\\ \hline 
    70   &   75\\ \hline 
    50   &   62 \\ \hline 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.7\textwidth}  
\only<2>{\begin{table}
 \tiny
  \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r}

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Descending Order}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Rank}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Descending Order}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Rank}} \\ \hline
86 & 1 & 61 & 21 \\ \hline
85 & 2.5 & 60 & 22 \\ \hline
85 & 2.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
79 & 8 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
73 & 13 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
70 & 14.5 & 45 & 34 \\ \hline
70 & 14.5 & 40 & 35.5 \\ \hline
65 & 17 & 40 & 35.5 \\ \hline
65 & 17 & 38 & 37 \\ \hline
65 & 17 & 30 & 38.5 \\ \hline
63 & 19 & 30 & 38.5 \\ \hline
62 & 20 & 20 & 40 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}}

  \onslide<3->{\begin{table}
 \tiny
  \begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r}

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Descending Order}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Rank}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Descending Order}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Rank}} \\ \hline
86 & 1 & \color{red}{61} & \color{red}{ 21} \\ \hline
85 & 2.5 & 60 & 22 \\ \hline
85 & 2.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 55 & 24.5 \\ \hline
80 & 5.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
79 & 8 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
75 & 10.5 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
73 & 13 & 50 & 30 \\ \hline
70 & 14.5 & 45 & 34 \\ \hline
70 & 14.5 & 40 & 35.5 \\ \hline
65 & 17 & 40 & 35.5 \\ \hline
65 & 17 & 38 & 37 \\ \hline
65 & 17 & 30 & 38.5 \\ \hline
63 & 19 & 30 & 38.5 \\ \hline
\color{red}{62} & \color{red}{20} & 20 & 40 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}}  
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\centering
\onslide<4-> Grand Median $= \frac{62 + 61}{2} = 61.5$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\begin{columns}[T]`

Comment: It'd be great if you, y'know, included a link to the duplicate question.

Comment: Please have a look at the very top of your question: "

This question already has an answer here:

    Avoiding jumping frames in beamer 5 answers

"

Answer (score -2):

```
\begin{columns}[T]
```

fixes it! Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98512)

Comment: Hello MrSampson. This was an automatically generated text from reviewing your answer. You cannot accept a comment as an answer. Normally the question then is closed as "off-topic", but in this case the answer can be found in an answer of another question. So nothing to do here. If you want, you can simply delete your answer and then everything is fine.

Comment: So, it's better to have a question left "unaswered" with an answering comment, then to add an "answer" as I did, showing it as answered? I see a big fat "-2" on votes because I put the word "Thanks" into the answer, but, y'know, it's marked as "answered."

Doesn't this strike you as silly?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right. When an answer to the question can be found in an answer of another question, this will be written in the most top block at the beginning of the question. Another possibility is that the question is closed as "off-topic" where also a comment can be found which can also hint to a comment in that the solution can be found.
Sometimes there is more than one solution to a problem and so it may be that a solution can be found in the "duplicate" question as well as in the comment.

Comment: If you want to **comment** which solution helped you when there is no answer given, you could upvote the comment that helped you (don't know if you need a minimum score to do it) and also comment yourself that another comment was helpful (for that you definitively need a minimum score; I think 15). If you don't have enough score to comment, you could also edit your question and state which comment helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: But you should *not* write an answer *yourself* (to *your* question) if someone else has provided the answer.
And to come back to the original point: If a question is closed (for whatever reason) it can't be really seen/interpreted as "unanswered".
Hopefully these comments helped you a bit ...