# How to keep the same layout with beamer animation?

Tags: beamer, animations

I have a problem with this slide: the layout of all the lines changes during the animation
Thank you for helping me

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}

\vspace{-1.25cm}
\begin{center}
Deux types de régime que l’on rencontre dans les installations électriques. Ils sont produits par des générateurs qui ont leur propre mode de fonctionnement.
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> Courant continu CC ("DC")
\begin{itemize}
\item<3-> Générateur électrochimique : pile, batterie
\item<4-> Générateur électronique : panneau solaire
\item<5-> Redressement du courant alternatif
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-2.25cm}\hspace{8cm}
\includegraphics<2->[width=2.75cm,keepaspectratio]{Figures/courantCC.png}
\item<6-> Courant alternatif CA ("AC")
\begin{itemize}
\item<7-> Alternateur : convertion de l'énergie \\ \,\,\,\,\,\,mécanique en énergie électrique
\end{itemize}

\vspace{-2.25cm}\hspace{8cm}
\includegraphics<6->[width=2.75cm,keepaspectratio]{Figures/courantAC.png}
\end{itemize}
  %\begin{block}{Comments, suggestions or bug reports ?}
   % Please send a mail at: \email{melmorabity@fedoraproject.org}
  %\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Avoiding jumping frames in beamer](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/148)

Comment: Your MWE's become better but you're not quite there. Please add the preamble, i.e. `\documentclass` and that stuff including the definitions of `\cro` and `\ahmed` or the package where they are defined and add `\end{document}` in such a way that everybody can just copy the code and compile it. (BTW, does it help if you just add `[t]` after `\begin{frame}`?)

Comment: No, it is not. Did you try to compile it as listed in your question? It won't compile. It MUST start with `\documentclass{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by [samcarter in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444897/121799), the jumping can simply avoided by adding `[t]` after `\begin{frame}`. And your code is a bit rusty, there is no reason to start itemize so often, especially if you use `columns`, which I suggest. You can use `[t]` here as well in order to avoid jumps. As pointed out by @AlexG, your MWE is not complete. This is an MWE. It starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled. Please consider to post documents in the future. (**EDIT**: samcarter pointed out that there were some `\,\,\,`, which I removed, and I also used the opportunity to redraw your pics with Ti*k*Z, which IMHO looks a bit better.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{center}
Deux types de régime que l’on rencontre dans les installations électriques. Ils sont produits par des générateurs qui ont leur propre mode de fonctionnement.
\end{center}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{8cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> Courant continu CC ("DC")
\item<3-> Générateur électrochimique : pile, batterie
\item<4-> Générateur électronique : panneau solaire
\item<5-> Redressement du courant alternatif
\item<6-> Courant alternatif CA ("AC")
\item<7-> Alternateur : convertion de l'énergie 
\begin{center}
mécanique en énergie électrique
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{4cm}
\only<2->{\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,scale=0.35]
\draw[orange] (0,1.6) -- (7,1.6);
\draw (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5) (0,0)node[left]{$0$} -- (7,0) node[above]{temps};
\node[text=blue!30,anchor=west,font=\small] at (-1.5,-4) {Courant continu (DC)};
\end{tikzpicture}\\}
\only<6->{\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,scale=0.35]
\draw[orange] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2*pi] ({1.05*\x},{2.5*sin(\x r)});
\draw (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5) (0,0)node[left]{$0$} -- (7,0) node[above]{temps};
\node[text=blue!30,anchor=west,font=\small] at (-1.5,-4) {Courant alternatif (AC)};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
  %\begin{block}{Comments, suggestions or bug reports ?}
   % Please send a mail at: \email{melmorabity@fedoraproject.org}
  %\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]